# spring mvc cannot find the jasper file in WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I created a spring MVC application. In that i used to create pdf report using jasper.
i put Jasper file sampleReport.jrxml and sampleReport.jasper inside the WEB-INF/report folder.

i tried to access file using

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/WEB-INF/report/sampleReport.jrxml");
            //InputStream xmlfil = new FileInputStream(new File(request.getContextPath()+File.separator
            //      + fileName + ".jrxml"));
            InputStream xmlfil = resource.getInputStream();
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(xmlfil);
```

but when execute it gives the error "/WEB-INF/report/sampleReport.jrxml" file not found.

I also tried this.

```
InputStream xmlfil = new FileInputStream(new File(request.getContextPath()+File.separator
            + fileName + ".jrxml"));
```

But no hope.

How to get the file in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Set your file under webapp.
eg. WebContent/report/sampleReport.jrxml

And try as below :

```
ServletContext context = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
    InputStream xmlfil = new FileInputStream(new File(context.getRealPath("/report/sampleReport.jrxml")));
```

Comment: webcontent or webapp?

Comment: there is no web content folder. it only have webapp, resources, and scr folders

Comment: ohh i see, i forget about spring mvc structure.it so please set under webapp.

Comment: how could we get context?